# Fitting of an image (matrix) to a bounded region in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, data-fitting

I want to fit an image in the bounded space of two circles.

***Explanation***:
I am drawing two circles of different radii and I want to fill the space between the two circles with an image. Both circles and the image to be filled in are produced by matlab and available in matrix form.

Answer (score 0):

If the circles are binary images, then you can do the following:

1. Use `imfill` to get a binary mask for each of the circles.
2. Logical AND the two masks to get the intersecting region.
3. Create a blank image (same size as the others).
4. Use the intersection mask from 2. to index both the blank image and the source image.

Starting after step 1., with the two binary masks *of the same size*:

```
BW12 = BW1 & BW2;
Iout = zeros(size(BW1));
Iout(BW12) = Iin(BW12);
```

If you want to draw the circles too, follow a similar approach with masks that represent the unfilled circles.

Comment: Thank you 'chappjc'. Could you please elaborate point 3 a bit more? I am relatively new to  Matlab.

Comment: `Iout = zeros(size(Iin));`

Comment: Thanks again. Please also tell me about the intersection mask you mentioned in point 4.

Comment: `mask_inter = mask1 & mask2;`

Comment: No actually. It may be because I am not able to use the intersection mask for the indexing.

Comment: OK, see the updated answer.  Indexing can be done with a logical mask of the same size as the image OR with a list of numerical linear indexes.